# meizu pro 5 OTA-10.2

Tags: fingerprint-reader

How can I get fingerprint to work. Missing a userguide for the OS. There is no place in the systemsettings where I can activate or log my fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't - as there is no support for the fingerprint reader in the system/API (and lots of other features you may have expected, probably).

Answer (score 0):

The fingerprint support is not implemented in Ubuntu Touch yet, but developers are probably working on it. You might want to follow this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-system-settings/+bug/1547040

However I don't know if ant ETA has been given.